# How do I integrate $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{5}}$?

Tags: integration

For integrate this integral with fraction $\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt[3]{5}}$

if $\sqrt[3]{5}$ must be derivated first to find *dx* ?

Comment: this is a constant, so $\int \frac{dx}{5^{1/3}}=\frac{1}{5^{1/3}} \cdot \int 1 dx$

Comment: Don't you miss a $x$ somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would just be $$\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{5}} + C$$ as it's just integrating a constant.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll use that next time

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt[3]{5}$ is a constant. The integral is equal to $\frac{x}{\sqrt[3]{5}}+c$